# JSON not printing properly using Spring and Hibernate 4.3.5

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have the following setup working fine and it's printing the following JSON as expected:

```
{
  "status" : {
    "status" : "SUCCESS",
    "message" : "  "
  },
  "employeeStatus" : [ {
    "ID" : 81,
    "Name" : "Jack"
  }, {
    "ID" : 88,
    "Name" : "Anthony"
  } ]
}
```

Following code works fine and prints above JSON:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/get_employee_details", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String updateemployee()
    {  
       MyJSON myJSON = new MyJSON("SUCCESS", "  ");
       myJSON.addEmployeeStatus(81, "Jack");
       myJSON.addEmployeeStatus(88, "Anthony");
       return myJSON;
    }


public class MyJSON {
    private MyStatus status;
    private List<EmployeeStatus> employeeStatus = new ArrayList<>();
    public MyJSON(String status, String message) {
        this.status = new MyStatus(status, message);
    }
    public void addEmployeeStatus(int id, String name) {
        this.employeeStatus.add(new EmployeeStatus(id, name));
    }
    public MyStatus getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }
    public List<EmployeeStatus> getEmployeeStatus() {
        return this.employeeStatus;
    }
}

public class MyStatus {
    private String status;
    private String message;
    public MyStatus(String status, String message) {
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return this.message;
    }
}


public class EmployeeStatus {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    public EmployeeStatus(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    @JsonProperty("ID")
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    @JsonProperty("Name")
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

But I have few more things involved like Hibernate 4.3.5 from where I am getting some details so I have modified the above code as follows:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/get_employee_details", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String updateemployee
    (
    @RequestParam(value="emp_id", defaultValue="0") Integer emp_id
    ) 
    {
       EmployeeDao empDao = (EmployeeDao)context.getBean("empDao");
       List<Employee> empList = empDao.findByEmId(emp_id);

       MyJSON myJSON = new MyJSON("SUCCESS", "  ");
       myJSON.addEmployeeStatus(empList);
       return myJSON;
   }


 public class MyJSON {
    private MyStatus status;
    private List<EmployeeStatus> employeeStatus = new ArrayList<>();
    public MyJSON(String status, String message) {
        this.status = new MyStatus(status, message);
    }
    public void addEmployeeStatus(List<Employee> empList) {
        this.employeeStatus.add(new EmployeeStatus(empList));
    }

    public MyStatus getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }
    public List<EmployeeStatus> getEmployeeStatus() {
        return this.employeeStatus;
    }
}


public class EmployeeStatus {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<Employee> empList;


    public EmployeeStatus(List<Employee> empList) {
        this.empList = empList;
    }

    @JsonProperty("ID")
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    @JsonProperty("Name")                                           
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

I am getting following JSON response for the above :

```
{
    "status": {
        "status": "SUCCESS",
        "message": "  "
    },
    "employeeStatus": [
        {
            "ID": 0,
            "Name": null
        }
    ]
}
```

In case if someone is wondering what's the output of `empList`. from the below line of code of the controller, I tried printing it like this :

```
List<Employee> empList = empDao.findByEmId(emp_id);

logger.info("Employee List Check " + empList);
```

and it's getting printed like this :

```
Employee List Check [abc.cde.myproject.orm.Employee@599eeded,abc.cde.myproject.orm.Employee@75ffa715,abc.cde.myproject.orm.Employee@152beb23 ]
```

Could anyone tell me what am I doing wriong above? I mean how can I print all the ID and Name in the JSON using `empList` from the above code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Convert list of Employee `List<Employee> empList` to JSON using any of the library like jakson,flexjson etc.

Create a method like below.

```
public String toJsonArray(Collection<Employee> collection) {
  return new JSONSerializer().transform(new DateTransformer("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"), java.util.Date.class).include("ID","Name").exclude("*").serialize(empList);
}
```

Note : Add flexjson dependency in you pom/gradle file so once you added dependency. imports will be like below.

```
import flexjson.JSONDeserializer;
import flexjson.JSONSerializer;
import flexjson.transformer.DateTransformer;
```